# Misunderstanding small detail in proof - svd analysis of gradient descent

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition, svd, gradient-descent

[Does gradient descent converge to a minimum-norm solution in least-squares problems?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3451272/does-gradient-descent-converge-to-a-minimum-norm-solution-in-least-squares-problem)

In this wonderful answer, the writer writes a proof that says to which value gradient descent will converge.

I'm trying to understand a simple detail.

It is implied that if $A = U\Sigma V^T$ and $y = V^Tx$, then $(I-A^TA)^kx = (I-\Sigma^T\Sigma)^ky$ and I am struggling more than I should be to understand why that is.

Shouldn't it be $ (I-V\Sigma^T\Sigma V^T)^kVy$?

Comment: I assume you're referring to my answer. Thank you for the praise.

Comment: I am. Thank you for the great answer. I will try to make full sense of it.

Comment: By the way, I contacted the corresponding author of the paper on arXiv and she confirmed that, indeed, the claim in the paper is incomplete.

Comment: Why is it incomplete? because of the issue I raised or is there something else at play?

Comment: If the initial state ${\rm x}_0$ is orthogonal to the null space of $\rm A$ then gradient descent will indeed converge to the least-norm solution. The authors forgot to mention the orthogonality requirement.

Comment: Ah I knew that.  I thought the proof was to show what it converges to, regardless of additional assumptions. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying to show is false, but you can get something close then you get the desired matrix $(I-\Sigma^T\Sigma)^k$ by considering the iteration this definition is used to construct.

$$
\begin{aligned}
(I-A^TA)^kx &= (I-V\Sigma^T\Sigma V^T)^kx \\
&= (VV^T-V\Sigma^T\Sigma V^T)^kx := (VDV^T)^kx,
\end{aligned}
$$
where $D = I-\Sigma^T\Sigma$.
$$
(VDV^T)^kx = VD^kV^Tx = VD^ky.
$$

I believe this is enough to proceed with the proof in the answer. Since you are forming an iteration between the $y$'s, you multiply both sides of the $x$ iteration by $V^T$, which cancels out the $V$, which yields the desired result.