# Why does the gradient descent of square loss result in minimizing the l2 norm in compressed sensing problem

Tags: optimization, signal-processing, least-squares, numerical-optimization, gradient-descent

Why is the gradient descent of this problem with an extremely small step size (start at $\mathbf{x_0}=\mathbf{0}$)
$$
\min_\mathbf{x} ||\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{A}\mathbf{x}||_2^2 
$$
equivalent to
$$
\min_\mathbf{x} ||\mathbf{x}||_2^2 s.t. \mathbf{y}=\mathbf{A}\mathbf{x}
$$
where $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{y}$ are vectors and $\mathbf{A}$ is a fat matrix.

It seems to be a common result but I cannot tell the why, could anyone help me with that?

Comment: Minimizing $\| y - Ax \|^2$ using gradient descent does not necessarily find the least norm solution to $Ax = y$. If the first iterate $x^0$ of gradient descent already satisfies $Ax^0 = y$ then gradient descent converges to $x^0$ (and the gradient descent iterates are all equal to $x^0$).

Comment: I'd be curious to see what you're referring to when you say this is a common result.

Comment: Oops, I forgot to mention that the gradient descent starts from x=0.  zero init.

Comment: The same question was asked here, and apparently a proof was given though I haven't checked it: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3451272/does-gradient-descent-converge-to-a-minimum-norm-solution-in-least-squares-probl

Comment: This isn't true for trivial reasons, for some step sizes gradient descent won't converge at all. There is not "one" gradient descent algorithm you can universally refer to in this context.

Comment: That proof works! Thanks so much!

Comment: Where's the compressed sensing problem?