# Looking for shortcut in linear system solving

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, pseudoinverse

Given a matrix A (possibly singular), a matrix B and a vector $\mathbf{y}$, I need to compute:

1. the last row of the matrix
   $$
   A^+B
   $$
2. the last entry of the vector
   $$
   A^+\mathbf{y}
   $$

Is my only option that of calculating the pseudo-inverse $A^+$, compute the inner product and then take the last row/entry? Or is there a shortcut?

Comment: Both questions boil down to the question how to calculate the last row of the pseudoinverse

Comment: why the downvolte? what is wrong with this question?

Comment: You want to calculate $e_n^TA^+B$. You may calculate $x^T=e_n^TA^+$ first and then calculate the vector-matrix product $x^TB$. So, you need to find not just any, but the **minimum-norm** least-square solution $x$ to $A^Tx=e_n$. I think the conjugate gradient method is able to do this. [Apparently](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3499305) some variants of gradient descent is also capable of finding the minimum-norm least square solution.